# Using Keras with Ensemble Voting Classifier

Tags: python, keras, ensemble-learning

I am trying to use `EnsembleVoteClassifier` from `mlxtend` library, where my classifiers are ANN, SVM, Logistic Regression. I am pre-fitting the models and calling `EnsembleVoteClassifier` just for prediction:

```
ensemble=EnsembleVoteClassifier(clfs=[model_nn, model_logreg],voting='hard',refit=False)
ensemble.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_ensemble = ensemble.predict(X_test)
```

The problem is with Keras. My code is below:

```
model_nn = Sequential()
model_nn.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), 
                kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42), 
                bias_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42)))

model_nn.add(Activation('relu'))
model_nn.add(BatchNormalization())
model_nn.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_nn.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 
model_nn.compile (loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4))

early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=20)
lr_reduce= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, mode='min', patience=20)

history = model_nn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, 
                    class_weight=class_weights, 
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val), verbose = 1, 
                    callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor, lr_reduce])
y_pred_nn = model_nn.predict(X_test)
y_pred_nn = y_pred_nn.argmax(axis=1)
```

The problem is that the shape of predicted class is `(n_samples,2)` which produces an error in EnsembleVoteClassifier:

`raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (, 2)`

Is there any way to pass the pipeline that will take care of the shape problem and output the keras prediction with the same shape as `sklearn` does?

Thank you.